# Hidden Service Communication with clear net

Tags: onion-services, ip-address-leak, clear-net

If a hidden service has to communicate with the clear net but doesnt want to either appear to be coming from a known tor exit and masking its true IP what would be the best way to achieve something like this?
Would a second hosted server and forwarding the data from HSserver to the nonHSserver and then out to teh clearnet be the best solution?

Comment: Well, yes but the service will not be hidden. A single hop proxy won't provide a lot of protection against an adversary with subpoena power, the ISP of the onion server or the ISP of the second server.

Answer (score 1):

An answer is simple: use a second HS! You're using a second HS as a proxy or OpenVPN server for the *very deep HS of yours*. And no problem will be regarding the privacy/location/deanonymization of your first HS